# Problem with android IME

Tags: android, ime

I am developing an IME for kannada - an Indian language by adapting softkeyboard from android sdk. When I type characters cursor moves ahead by one place. But when I type some compound characters like kku in bekku, I will have to combine, ka, virama, ka and then u with 4 different unicode characters. All of them appear together, but cursor will be 4 places ahead instead of appearing next to the compound character. How can I show the cursor in the correct location? I tried setSelection() method of inputconnection. I also tried sending keyevent (down and up both) of key-dpad-left. Nothing is working. 
Thanks in advance